# Create bounding box from a single point lat long?

Tags: javascript, maps, bounding-box, turfjs

Im trying to create an 8km bounding box from a single point lat long.

So for example if i have the lat long 51.508394925082406, -0.12786049901934773 which is in London but i want to find what the bounding box would be 8km from this point, ive tried using packages like turf but they only help if you have to bounding box or if your coordinates are a linestring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a 8km buffer around the point, and get the bounding box of the buffer.

```
const p = turf.point([-0.12786049901934773, 51.508394925082406]);
buffer = turf.buffer(p, 8, {units: 'kilometers'});
bbox = turf.bbox(buffer);
poly = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox);
```